# ckeditor5 duplicated modules error in nuxt 3

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt.js, ckeditor, nuxtjs3, ckeditor5

I have used the ckEditor 5 `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^40.2.0",` in my Nuxt 3 project and I want to upload images within the editor and for that I have used plugin `CKBox` `"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox": "^40.2.0",` but when I import this plugin as mentioned below it return the [error](https://i.imgur.com/ieMbGVi.png) `ckeditor-duplicated-modules`

I configured the editor on a separate plugin file

```js
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
    nuxtApp.vueApp.use(CKEditor)
})
```

```js
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import { ImageUpload } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image';
import { CKBox, CKBoxImageEdit } from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckbox";
const editorConfig = {
  plugins: [  ImageUpload, CKBox, CKBoxImageEdit, /* ... */ ],
};
```

I have used the [this example](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/vuejs-v3.html#javascript) from ckeditor's official website